# How to get ActionBar "customView" width

Tags: java, android, kotlin, toolbar, android-toolbar

How can I get the **width of the `customView`** of the toolbar/actionbar as **highlighted** below?

[image]

I had the idea to get the whole screenWidth and substract the x coordinate of the "custom area" but I can't/don't know how get the x coordinate of that.

```kotlin
val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
val screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels

val toolbar= mainActivity.findViewById<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)

val location = IntArray(2)
mainActivity.supportActionBar?.customView?.getLocationOnScreen(location)
val x = location[0]
val customViewWidth = screenWidth - x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi i have this solution to get the value of x it's work fine for me the idea is getting the toolbar from action Bar and the textView from toolBar:

```
private void getX() {
    // to get ViewContainer from ActionBar
    int id = getWindow().getDecorView().getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_container", "id", getPackageName());
    ViewGroup v = findViewById(id);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() returned: " + v.getChildCount());
    int childCount = v.getChildCount();
    //  The view tree observer can be used to get notifications when global events, like layout, happen.
    v.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                if (v.getChildAt(i) instanceof Toolbar) {
                    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) v.getChildAt(i);
                    int toolBarChild = toolbar.getChildCount();
                    for (int j = 0; j < toolBarChild; j++) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: " + toolbar.getChildAt(j));
                        if (toolbar.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView) {
                            TextView tx = (TextView) toolbar.getChildAt(i);
                            int x = tx.getLeft();
                            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: " + x); // this to get the Value of ox ( left of title )
                            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: " + tx.getText()); // this return title in action bar
                            /*
                            your code
                             */
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

hope that's help you

Comment: Hi, it crashed and print out the following: ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: requireActivity().findViewById(id) must not be null```

Comment: on which line you got the error ? for me i tested this code on onCreate() in my activity

Comment: if you have a n instance of your Toolbar you can use `getChildAt()` to find the TextView and from it you can get the value of X like my second for loop

Comment: Dont forget to remove the observer when you get your x if you don't need it again

Comment: I don't use the observer, as I already have access to the toolbar